# startSSL.com - free HTTPS certificates?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I just published my website on a free host. My web address is `mydomain.usa.cc`. Can I put a free certificate from startSSL on my website? Will it work?

Comment: StartSSL certificates are no longer trusted by most browsers: [StartSSL certificate gives SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE in Firefox and ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/startssl-certificate-gives-sec-error-revoked-certificate-in-firefox-and-err-cert)

Answer (score 1):

I just learn that I can't use a freeSSL for a subdomain.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. You do not own the parent domain. Good work!

Comment: Yep, this is not possible. Maybe get your own domain? :-)